# z-index values not working the way it should - z-index 50 item shows up underneath

Tags: html, css, position, z-index, layer

http://new.michaellane.com/listing-gallery.php

The yellow strips of paper you see there have this set:

```
.listing_specs {
    width:230px;
    height:140px;
    background-image:url('/images/featured_listing_specs.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#836637;
    padding-top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    right:-120px;
    z-index:50;
}
```

And the div that contains it, .listing_icons, is just a generic float:left, position:relative DIV with a z-index of only 10.

How is it that the yellow strips come underneath the .listing_icons on the right hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `z-index` of all the `grid_8 alpha listing_gallery_icon` on the left side to 11.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the z-index from .listing_gallery_icon:

```
.listing_gallery_icon {
  position:relative;
  /*z-index:10;*/
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. at least on Firefox so far. How does this logic work??

Comment: What version of IE are you using? (The logic is that you're creating a new stacking context for every single 'listing gallery icon.' Anything inside the icon will be relative to that stacking context, so all the icons are "10", all the "listing specs" are "10.50" not just 50. Because they're all at the same height it stacks them by the order they appear in the source.)

Comment: Yup i understand that now.. it's just that, divs created later on in the code still come on TOP of the previous ones, so explicit z-indexing was necessary. I took the other answer - about alternating between z-index 10 and 11 and that worked out for me. I understand the issue better now, thanks so much.. I wish I could split the point credits.

Comment: Giving them all z-index 10 does nothing though, it just goes back to resolving them by order. alternating 11/10 does what you want but is still strictly unnecessary. (I suspect the problem in IE was that it falsely creates a new stacking context because you specified 'position:relative'. My next suggestion would have been to remove that too)

This is a very very good article explaining z-indices, and it also lists the bug you were encountering in IE7: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Answer (score 0):

Its because the div on the right its not relative for the note on the left.

try setting the right:-120px; to 0. Is that the desired effect?

Comment: No, I want them to fly-out on mouse-over only... so usually you won't see the whole thing. positioning is correct.. just the layers were an issue.